# Twitter Bootstrap jQuery Calendar component week view to be show column wise

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, calendar

I've implemented Twitter Bootstrap jQuery Calendar component which working fine, but wants to show in week view design in column wise.

It is default as row wise I added my code here.

I attached my screen shot also please give me suitable answer please.

```
<% _.each(months, function(name) { %>
<div class="cal-cell1 <%= cal._getDayClass('week', start) %>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<%= cal._getHolidayName(start) %>"><%= name %><br>
<small><span data-cal-date="<%= start.getFullYear() %>-<%= start.getMonthFormatted() %>-<%= start.getDateFormatted() %>" data-cal-view="day">
    <%= start.getDate() %> <%= cal.locale['ms' + start.getMonth()] %></span></small>
</div>
        <% start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1); %>
    <% }) %>
</div>
<hr>
<%= cal._week() %>![enter image description here][1]
```

[image]

Comment: highlighted are in row wise. i want to be show in column wise.. where should i change

Answer (score 0):

use this code

<% _.each(months, function(name) { %>